# groupby function: df.groupby(by=["b"]).sum()

Tags: python, pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

This doc gives an example of groupby function:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, None, 4], [2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["a", "b", "c"])

    a   b    c
0   1   2.0  3
1   1   NaN  4
2   2   1.0  3
3   1   2.0  2

 df.groupby(by=["b"]).sum()

  output:
         a   c
    b
    1.0  2   3
    2.0  2   5
```

I do not understand how the output like this?

Comment: it groups the data by the values in column B, and sum's the other numeric columns. For example, when B was 2.0, C was 3 and 2, and it's sum is 5.

Comment: yes, thank you so much for the explanation. Magic Pandas!